# Using afconvert from iOS

Tags: ios, audio, file-sharing, afconvert

Does anyone know if it is possible to convert a sound file in the Documents directory from within an app? I have a recorded sound file that will be available in iTunes File Sharing that I need to convert. Is afconvert available from within iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure from what format to what format you want to convert to, but converting audio during runtime is not as simple as the command-line afconvert tool.

Check out Apple's sample projects [iPhoneACFileConvertTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneACFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html) or [ConvertFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ConvertFile/Introduction/Intro.html). I think these would be good starting points if you want to convert audio in your app.

Comment: This suggestion led me to the iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest sample project which is exactly what I needed for my project (Needed to be able to change the sampling rate of a file).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, afconvert is just a handy command-line interface to the features of the ExtAudioFile API which you can find in  -- Using this API you can convert from any supported file format/audio format combination TO any supported file format/audio format combination.